# Place nodes in tikz axis using csvreader

Tags: tikz-pgf, csvsimple

I'm trying to place nodes inside a TikZ axis using `\csvreader` command from `simplecsv` package. However, somehow, the following does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{xx.csv}
xv,yv,z
1.0,2.2,3.0
2.0,3.2,1.0
\end{filecontents*}

    \maketitle
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,
            ymin=0,
            xmax=4,
            ymax=4,
        ]
            \node at (axis cs:2, 2) {x};
            \csvreader[head to column names]{xx.csv}{}{
                \node at (axis cs:\xv, \yv) {y};
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I always get a `Argument of \pgfmathfloatparse@@ has an extra }.`. Does anybody spot what is going wrong here? I've been trying this for a while now..

I've put this snippet on Overleaf. Please feel free to investigate it there: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gdczbgvqmrzt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really answer the question as stated, but it shows how to get `nodes near coords` with `\SI`. From your comment to Nico's answer this seems to be what you're after in the end. I'll just delete this if it isn't what you need, or if you feel it's not the right place for it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{xx.csv}
xv,yv,z
1.0,2.2,3.0
2.0,3.2,1.0
\end{filecontents*}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,
            ymin=0,
            xmax=4,
            ymax=4,
        ]
        \addplot [
            mark=none,
            draw=none,
            nodes near coords={\SI{\pgfplotspointmeta}{\m}}
            ] 
            table[
              x=xv,
              y=yv,
              meta=z,
              col sep=comma,
              point meta=explicit symbolic
              ] {xx.csv};
            
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, csvsimple, siunitx}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{xx.csv}
 xv,yv,z
 1.0,2.2,3.0
 2.0,3.2,1.0
\end{filecontents*}
            
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \csvreader[head to column names]{xx.csv}{xv=\x,yv=\y,z=\val}{
    \begin{axis}[
         xmin=0,
         ymin=0,
         xmax=4,
         ymax=4
         ]
    \node at (axis cs:2, 2) {x};
    \node[draw] at (axis cs:\x,\y){\SI{\val}{\metre\per\second}};
    \end{axis}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not suffice in my case. I need detailed control over the apparence of nodes. To be precise, I want to draw boxes according to the given coordinates and then place the value from the `z`-column inside the nodes and format it using `siunitx`. The example given above is really only a minimal example that reproduces the error that I'm getting. I know that I can also place nodes at scatter coordinates using `meta` and that I can control the apparence of nodes as well only using `pgfplots` options. However, I think I cannot get `siunitx` in there for number formatting.

Comment: Ok, I see. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for that! I've been using the other approach now, since this is a little more elegant. However, thank's for your efforts!